# Using php-ldap in Centos 6.3

Tags: php, centos, openldap

I'm trying to build a LDAP interface using php but have run into this strange problem. I have installed the php-ldap package using yum on my base php install but whenever I call ldap_connect() it says the function is undefined. Seeing phpinfo() I can verify that the ldap extension is indeed installed and enabled.

Answer (score 29):

Are you sure you have openldap included?

I just realized I have the same issue where phpinfo shows me several other *ldap* modules loaded by apache, but I do no have openldap

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

I just got a successful install following the directions here: http://www.aoddy.com/2009/01/18/how-to-install-php-ldap-module-on-centos5/

Instructions from link:

- `yum install php-ldap`
- `vi /etc/php.ini`

  - add `extension=ldap.so`
- `service httpd restart`

Comment: Thanks @dgibbs its working for me :-)  I have installed it for Linux 7  just hit _ yum install php-ldap_ and _service httpd restart_